# Message Edit Pycord

Tags: python, pycord

I am trying to edit a suggestion to accept a suggestion, I want to edit a embeds title using the message ID, The messsage ID is stored in my db and the user would go left click the suggestion to get the id and then would run this command to accept it
/suggestaccept (MessageID) (NewEmbedTitle)
But it returns

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jackd\Documents\Felbcord Py.venv\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 993, in invoke_application_command
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\jackd\Documents\Felbcord Py.venv\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 357, in invoke
await injected(ctx)
File "C:\Users\jackd\Documents\Felbcord Py.venv\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 134, in wrapped
raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'

````
import discord
from pymongo import MongoClient
from discord.ext.commands import slash_command
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Cog

class Suggestions(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self,bot,*args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.bot = bot
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label="Your Suggestion: ", style=discord.InputTextStyle.long))

async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        m = await interaction.response.send_message("Suggestion send!", ephemeral=True)
        suggest = discord.Embed(title=f"Suggestion by {interaction.user} Under Review ",color=discord.Color.blue())
        suggest.add_field(name="Your Suggestion: ", value=self.children[0].value)
        suggest.set_footer(text=f"Message id: {m.id} ")
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(987396375069224960)
        embed = await channel.send(embed=suggest)
        await embed.add_reaction('☑')
        await embed.add_reaction('❌')
        db = self.bot.mongoConnect["FelBot"]
        collection = db["FelBot"]
        await collection.find_one({'_id' : m.id})
        await collection.insert_one( {'_id': m.id})

class Suggest(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot


@slash_command(name="suggest", description="suggestions")
    @commands.cooldown(1,7200, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def modal_slash(self,ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
        await ctx.send_modal(Suggestions(self.bot, title="Suggestion"))

@slash_command(name="suggestaccept",description="Accept a suggestion")
    async def suggestaccept(self,ctx, m_id: discord.Option(str, description="Message id."),new_embed:discord.Option(str, description="New embed")):
     m = self.bot.get_message(m_id)
     await m.edit(new_embed=new_embed)
     await ctx.respond('Accepted suggestion by {interaction.user}')
     


def setup(bot):
   bot.add_cog(Suggest(bot))```
````

Comment: This line `m = self.bot.get_message(m_id)` results `m` being None, resulting in your error on the next line. 
Maybe it is comparing a string vs integer? m.id == m_id ??

Comment: May you explain how to fix this? I am confused and have tried myself

Comment: `m_id: discord.Option(str...` you set the type as string, while the documentation says that the `id` of a message is of type integer. You just have to alter the type `m_id: discord.Option(int, description...)`

Answer (score 0):

You set `m_id` as a str. Convert it to an int. Also when editting the message it needs to be `embed=new_embed`